# Why is TextView throwing this error?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, baseadapter

The following code is for populating a list using BaseAdapter in Xamarin.
The problem is, in GetView() function when I change the text of TextView, it throws the

`Object Reference not set to an instance of an object`

exception. Screenshot is attached for detail ...
[image: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object]

Following code is .axml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialogContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:paddingBottom="25dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Default Contact" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this following code is of `GetView()` function:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView ?? _Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SelectContactsItem, parent, false);

    var textView = _Context.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.contact);
    Console.WriteLine (_ContactList.ElementAt(position).Name);
    textView.Text = _ContactList.ElementAt (position).Name;
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about xamarin syntax but...you may doing something wrong here.

```
 var textView = _Context.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.contact);
                ^^^^^^^^
```

replace this line with...

```
 var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.contact);
```

[Rererence Link](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/create_a_custom_adapter_for_contacts/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView ?? _Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SelectContactsItem, parent, false);

    var textView = _Context.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.contact);
    Console.WriteLine (_ContactList.ElementAt(position).Name);
    textView.Text = _ContactList.ElementAt (position).Name;
    return view;
}
```

with this

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView ?? _Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SelectContactsItem, parent, false);

    var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.contact);
    Console.WriteLine (_ContactList.ElementAt(position).Name);
    textView.Text = _ContactList.ElementAt (position).Name;
    return view;
}
```

Comment: that exception is now on this line (var textView = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.contact);)